# How flatten a list with many arrays inside using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list, flatten

I am finding this very hard to understand and where to start, so I was hoping that some one would be able to point in the correct direction. I have a list(customers) inside which there are arrays/lists. Basically I want to flatten all the results of the list into a flat version if the list.

```
public class Customer : EntityBase
{
    public Phonenumber[]      PhoneNumbers            { get; set; }
    public Contact            BillToContact           { get; set; }
    public Terms              Terms                    { get; set; }
 }

 public class Contact
 {
    public Phonenumber[]        PhoneNumbers     { get; set; }
    public Address              Address          { get; set; }
    public Key                  Key              { get; set; }
    public string               CompanyName      { get; set; }
    public string               Email            { get; set; }
    public string               FirstName        { get; set; }
}

public class Phonenumber
{
    public string               Number            { get; set; }
    public int                  Key               { get; set; }
}

public class Terms
{
    public int      DueDays                       { get; set; }
    public int      DiscountDays                  { get; set; }
}


public class Address
{
    public string               Address1                    { get; set; }
    public string               Address2                    { get; set; }
    public string               City                        { get; set; }
    public string               Country                     { get; set; }
}

public abstract class EntityBase
{
    public Guid   Id          { get; set; }
    public string Status      { get; set; }
    public int    Rev         { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried many approaches and just keep getting more confused. So if anyone could help or even point me in the right direction I would be extremely grateful. below is one of the approaches I have tried.

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> Find (Func<Customer , bool> predicate) {

     foreach (var p in Customer.SelectMany(p => p)) {
             if(predicate(p)) {
             yield return p;
          }
       }
     }
```

I am Deserializing a jason string into a list but then want to display in a datagrid, but igGrid does not support binding to nested(complex) properties. So I need to flatten the list so that  there is no sub levels of the list.

Comment: You want a list of _what_?

Comment: what is your input? you already have a flat `IEnumerable<Customer>`, what are you trying to flatten?

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of all phone numbers for all customers? That's the only array I'm seeing.

Comment: I have a List<Customer> inside of which for example is phone numbers, so for that example i have many phone numbers I would like them to be in the first level.

Comment: You can do this, but your problem is that if the target is an object, it would have a different structure for each instance of the object.  Sounds messy.  It might be helpful if you explained what you are trying to accomplish by doing this.  Would you mind?

Comment: I am Deserializing a jason string into a list but then want to display in a datagrid but gGrid does not support binding to nested(complex) properties. So I need to flatten the list so that is no sub levels of the list.

Comment: If you are trying to flatten that whole structure, you are going to have issues with all the different columns since you have both contact and customer phone numbers that will all be stacked up with different column names.  The query would be pretty convoluted as well.  Can you possibly redesign your UI to use the information in a more natural manner, or be more clear about which columns you would like to flatten?

Answer (score 0):

To select an array of `PhoneNumber` from `List<Customer>` use `SelectMany`:

```
List<Customer> customers = [data];
PhoneNumber phoneNumbers = customers.SelectMany(x=>x.PhoneNumbers).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear at all from your question what output you actually want. Do you just want a list of all the phone numbers? Or do you want to preserve the other `Customer` information, such that you get multiple instances of the `Customer` information, each instance with a separate phone number?

You can accomplish the former with something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Phonenumber> numbers =
    customers.SelectMany(
        customer => customer.PhoneNumbers
                            .Concat(BillToContact.PhoneNumbers));
```

If you only want the `Customer.PhoneNumbers` numbers and not those in the `BillToContact` object, just leave the `.Concat(BillToContact.PhoneNumbers)` out of the above.

If you want to preserve one or more values from the original `Customer` object, you can do something like this:

```
var numbers = customers.SelectMany(
    customer => customer.PhoneNumbers.Select(
        number => new
        {
            Number = number, 
            FirstName = customer.BillToContact.FirstName,
            Email = customer.BillToContact.Email
        }));
```

The above will generate an enumeration of anonymous type objects, each having a single phone number, along with the corresponding `FirstName` and `Email` values from the associated `Contact` object. You can of course mix and match (e.g. use `.Concat(...)` to include phone numbers from the `BillToContact` object), and include whichever specific `Customer` or `Contact` members you want.